# Which will be stronger for securing a cantilever umbrella in a deck

Tags: materials, strength, building-physics, mechanical-failure

I am securing a cantilever umbrella baseplate to a deck. The decking timber will be reinforced with a pine nog between the deck joists.

The options that I have are to use 10mm stainless steel coach screw that will be embedded into a 70mm nog.

Alternatively I can use a 10mm bolt, washer and nylock nut that will be secured through a 50mm nog.

The timber will be the same grade wet H5 pine. The deck plate is the same size and thickness, as is the material of the screw / bolt.

Which method will be stronger. I can't use a longer bolt due to the limitation of space under the decking timber in order to fit the nut.

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps a plate to spread the load rather than a washer under the nog?

Comment: can you provide a sketch of what you plan to do?